# R write.table function inserts unwanted empty line at the bottom of my csv

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I have this code:

```
 write.table(df, file = f, append = F, quote = TRUE, sep = ";",
              eol = "\n", na = "", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"))
```

where df is my data frame and f is a .csv file name.
The problem is that the resulting csv file has an empty line at the end.
When I try to read the file:

```
dd<-read.table(f,fileEncoding = "UTF-8",sep = ";",header = T,quote = "\"")
```

I get the following error:

```
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader
```

Is there something I am missing?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: I solved the problem deleting the UTF-8 file encoding into the read.table:

```
dd<-read.table(f,sep = ";",header = T,quote = "\"")
```

but I can't explain the reason of this, since the default for write.table seems to be UTF-8 anyway (I checked this using an advanced text tool).

Any idea of why this is happening?
Thank you,

Comment: Your code works for me when using df <- iris. Could it be an issue with your data?

Comment: @JohnBee thank you I'll try to find out